# Alternative to @data in NASM32

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm learning assembly right now and I realized that the symbol `@data` isn't defined in NASM. Here is my code:

```
section .data
    var1 db 0x3
    var2 db 0x4

section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax, @data
    mov ds, eax
    
    mov eax, var1
    mov ebx, var2
    
    mov eax, 0
```

I search the web for alternative symbols and I didn't found anything. So is there any alternative to `@data` at all? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `seg var1` should work.

Comment: What is your target environment? On windows or linux 32 bit you don't need to mess with `ds` as you have a flat memory model.

Comment: @Jester Windows 32 bit, so does `ds` set up automatically?

Comment: Yes, you get `ds` initialized.

Comment: @Jester But when I debugging the code with IDA (without the first two lines in `main`), the `eax` and the `ebx` show wrong values... and the address is `unk_40020000`.

Comment: They are not wrong probably. Your expectation is likely what's wrong.

Comment: @Matan: What exactly do you see, and what were you expecting to see?

Comment: Nevermind, I just forgot to add `[]` in the variables. Anything works now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbol `@data` represents the paragraph address of the first byte of `data` segment in some assemblers. See also the example of 16bit .EXE file at [NASM Chapter 9](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.1). Loading segment registers before accessing data is essential in **real-mode 16bit programs for DOS or Windows 3**. When such program starts, its DS and ES point to *Program Segment Prefix* structure, not to the `data` segment of your program. When was the segment declared, assembler also created a relocatable symbol with corresponding name, such as `@data` or `data`, which can be used in your program to initialize segment register. Other assemblers may use a different syntax, for instance [MOV AX,PARA# [data]](https://euroassembler.eu/prodos16/tmac16.htm).

When a **flat 32|64bit protected-mode program** starts, its segment registers are already preloaded with valid indexes to [Segment Descriptor Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_descriptor) and you don't have to care about segment registers at all.