# I am having trouble printing strings in assembly

Tags: assembly, printing, dos, x86-16, masm

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


.data
    message db "Hello $"
.code
main PROC
    
    mov ax, seg message
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    

main ENDP
END main
```

An assembly tutorial gave me this code saying that it is what to use in order to print strings in assembly, but it isn't working. There is an error(A2022) on line 14, instruction operands must be the same size, and another error(A2004) on line 12, symbol type conflict. I'm very new and have no clue how to remedy this.

Comment: What assembler, what options, what else do you have in the file (as otherwise these would not be lines 12 and 14)? Make sure you target 16 bit real mode DOS if you intend to use this code.

Comment: The question [Alternative to @data in NASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780603/alternative-to-data-in-nasm32) might help you.

Comment: I assume this is MASM from the way it uses error numbers like A2022, not NASM.

Comment: If you're using Irvine**32**, presumably you're building 32-bit code, so addresses are 32-bit.  Use Irvine32 WriteString.  DOS system-calls won't work in native Windows programs.