# In Assembly language, is .DATA? a real thing?

Tags: assembly, masm, emu8086, dosbox

Today in my university lecture, we learned about uninitialized variables in Assembly, and that you have to use this specific data segment to do it: .DATA? where the '?' means that you won't initialize the variables, so there won't be any useless memory reserved. I cannot find anything about this on the internet, not even my compiler (emu8086) recognizes it. Am I missing something? Here is an example code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK
.DATA?
adat DB 100 DUP (?)
.CODE
main proc
MOV AX, DGROUP 
MOV DS, AX
LEA BX, adat
CALL read_string 
CALL cr_lf 
CALL write_string 
MOV AH,4Ch 
INT 21h
main endp
```

DGROUP is also unrecognized, and the rest of the code just has the procedures.

In the actual lecture we use DOSBOX, but I can't even install that on my laptop it's so old. I'm sure the code works with DOSBOX, I just don't know why.

Comment: Uninitialized data not stored in the executable is called `.bss` on modern systems (where it's actually guaranteed to be zero-initialized, so compilers can use it for global / static `int array[100];`.  Unlike DOS where it really did have whatever old values were left around.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-data-q?view=msvc-170

Comment: "In the actual lecture we use DOSBOX, but I can't even install that on my laptop it's so old. I'm sure the code works with DOSBOX, I just don't know why." DOSBox is not an assembler. You're probably referring to some assembler (eg MASM, TASM, JWASM) running in DOSBox. These assemblers may support a `.DATA?` directive.

Comment: Looks like the professor uses MASM while you are using a different assembler.  Note also that assembly is *assembled* with an *assembler,* not *compiled* with a *compiler.*

Comment: Also, DOSBOX has pretty low resource requirements.  It should definitely run on whatever laptop you have.  Get that checked out.

Answer (score 3):

> .DATA? where the '?' means that you won't initialize the variables, so there won't be any useless memory reserved.

The difference between .DATA and .DATA? is not about the memory but about the executable file (the .EXE or .COM). Everything in .DATA will get included in the file, not so for the items in .DATA?
Once the Operating System (DOS) has loaded the program, both the .DATA and .DATA? sections  will occupy their assigned memories.

> not even my compiler (emu8086) recognizes it.

Look it up in the manual that comes with emu8086. If .DATA? is not recognized, then try an alternate form like .BSS.

> and that you have to use this specific data segment to do it: .DATA?

That's by no means an obligation. You can always just add it to the normal DATA section and just accept a bunch of zero bytes in the file. It doesn't matter that much (in emu8086 programs).

```
.DATA
somevalue DW 12345
adat      DB 100 DUP (?)
```

And if you make sure that these zero-filled buffers are the last items in the .DATA section, then it's entirely possible that an intelligent assembler would not include those zero-bytes in the executable file.

Comment: The only other problem I have now is this error: 
wrong parameters: MOV  AX, DGROUP
probably no zero prefix for hex; or no 'h' suffix; or wrong addressing; or undefined var: DGROUP

Comment: @ElemérÚramKalapós SMALL memory model keeps only one data segment, there is no need to group data segments into DGROUP. Load `DS` with the paragraph address of `DATA`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780603/alternative-to-data-in-nasm32/65781586